# Excel: Group all rows with a same column value and remove duplicates in each group based on another column value

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, duplicates

I have an excel table with columns - `Date`, `Time`, `Name`

There are multiple row entries of the same `Name` on the same `Date`.

I want to keep only one entry for each `Name` for a single `Date`.

So, I need to group all rows with a same `Date` and remove duplicates in each group based on the `Name`. I know this is easy to do in SQL or using Python, but is there a way to do so in excel?

Comment: The Group By function in PowerQuery perhaps? Or just a Pivot Table? It's possible using Excel functions too. If you need more help, just add sample data and expected results.

Comment: Exactly, which rows are you planning to keep? The ones with the smallest/greatest time or is there another criterion?

Comment: It doesn't matter which ones I keep. I actually managed to solve this by using the remove duplicates functionality of excel and setting the columns `Date` and `Name` in the options